# Getting the value of TextView , update in the fragment when a button is clicked and called onClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, textview, onclicklistener

How to update the textview of a fragment from the button's onclickListner of the same fragement.

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_practicing_alphabet, container, false);
             TextView singleAlphabet=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.single_alphabet);
            ImageButton previousImage=(ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_backward_arrow);

previousImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    String tempAlphaString=(String) singleAlphabet.getText();
                    char tempAlphaChar=(char) (tempAlphaString.charAt(0)+1);
                    singleAlphabet.setText(tempAlphaChar);

                }});
```

I am getting an compilation error when accessing the singleAlphabet TextView,how to acees the textview and please give me some ideas how to update the textview.

Answer (score 0):

try to access the TextView like following code:

```
String tempAlphaString= single_Alphabet.getText().toString();
```

you can update TextView by

```
 single_Alphabet.setText("your text");
```